# Android Studio Java error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I tried to run android-studio and i get this error:(in the studio it self)

> Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\User.AndroidStudioPreview\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

the problem is why it's trying to use `jdk1.7.0_21` and not `jdk1.7.0_25`?(that what i got installed).
my Environment Variables are: (System variables)

```
Java_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25.
ANDROID_SWT: C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\tools\lib\x86.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed my problem by doing this:
Go into **File > Project Structure** (or use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and then under *Platform Settings* 
Click on "SDKs" and then delete the "1.7" JDK and add new JDK using the correct JAVA PATH.